# Properties file load to replace value in spring batch XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, spring-batch

Since a day i'm working on an issue. To make my code easier to maintain, I want to set all the constant i need in Spring Batch in a propertie file (My_Project/src/main/resources/spring/batch/config/batch.properties).

I search on the web several example ans nothing works. For this I replace my constant by ${constantNameInPorpertiesFile}

My context.xml
My_Project/src/main/resources/spring/batch/config/context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

 <!-- stored job-meta in memory-->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/batch/config/batch.properties"/>
</beans>
```

In this context.xml I expect that
 "" will replace my constant in the will which import the context.xml.

For example this spring batch file (My_Project/src/main/resources/spring/batch/jobs/CreateSpecificationFileJob.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/batch/config/batch.properties"/>

<import resource="../config/context.xml"/>  

<!-- Flow for the V4 specification file creation -->
<flow id="createSpecificationFileFlow" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <step id="formRecognitionPartitionerStep">
        <partition partitioner="formRecognitionPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="syncTaskExecutor" />
            <!-- partitioner will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext values.      -->
            <step>
                <flow parent="createAndCompleteSpecificationFile"/>
            </step>
        </partition>
    </step>
</flow>

<!-- sub-Flow to make all process on each form -->  
<flow id="createAndCompleteSpecificationFile" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="createSpecificationFile" next="sheetRecognitionPartitionerStep">
        <tasklet ref="createSpecificationFileTasklet"/>
    </step>

    <step id="sheetRecognitionPartitionerStep">
        <partition partitioner="sheetRecognitionPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="syncTaskExecutor" />
            <!--partitioner will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext values. -->
            <step>
                <flow parent="completeSheet"/>
            </step>
        </partition>
    </step>
</flow>

<!-- sub-Flow to make all process on each sheet of a form -->   
<flow id="completeSheet" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="gridRecognition" next="labelRecognition">
        <tasklet ref="gridRecognitionTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="labelRecognition" next="putDataInV4SpecificationFile">
        <tasklet ref="labelRecognitionTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="putDataInV4SpecificationFile" next="constantManagement">
        <tasklet ref="putDataInV4SpecificationFileTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="constantManagement" next="fileHeaderAndFooter">
        <tasklet ref="constantManagementTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="fileHeaderAndFooter" next="sheetLayoutForPrinting">
        <tasklet ref="fileHeaderAndFooterTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="sheetLayoutForPrinting">  
        <tasklet ref="sheetLayoutForPrintingTasklet"/>
    </step> 
</flow>


<!-- List of tasklet -->
<bean id="createSpecificationFileTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.CreateSpecificationFileTasklet" scope="step" >
    <property name="${partitionner.list_of_sheet}" value="#{stepExecutionContext['${partitionner.list_of_sheet}']}" />
</bean>
<bean id="gridRecognitionTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.read.GridRecognitionTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="${partitionner.sheet}" value="#{stepExecutionContext['${partitionner.sheet}']}" />
</bean>
<bean id="labelRecognitionTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.read.LabelRecognitionTasklet" scope="step"/>
<bean id="putDataInV4SpecificationFileTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.PutDataInV4SpecificationFileTasklet" scope="step"/>
<bean id="constantManagementTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.ConstantManagementTasklet" scope="step"/>
<bean id="fileHeaderAndFooterTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.FileHeaderAndFooterTasklet" scope="step"/>
<bean id="sheetLayoutForPrintingTasklet" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.SheetLayoutForPrintingTasklet" scope="step"/>

<bean id="syncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor"/>

<!-- List of partition -->
<bean id="formRecognitionPartitioner" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.FormRecognitionPartitioner" scope="step"/>
<bean id="sheetRecognitionPartitioner" class="com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.SheetRecognitionPartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="${partitionner.list_of_sheet}" value="#{jobExecutionContext['${partitionner.list_of_sheet}']}" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

This flow is launch by a job. Without any constant.
The error is: 
- Invalid property '${partitionner.list_of_sheet}' of bean class        [com.sopra.ner.specification.excel.write.CreateSpecificationFileTasklet] ................

When i open the file in target folder, the value is not replace.

If you have any idea to solve this i will be grateful.

Comment: You cannot replace property names like that only values.

Comment: Only value can be replace by this process? What can i use to replace the constant in my case?

Comment: Nothing, you would have to write your own `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to do something like that. (If that would even work). Also I don't really see the added use of specifying the name of the property as an attribute. Next to that in your current setup it would replace the name with the value. So I think you must be mixing up things...

Comment: Thanks for your help M.Deinum. I think my code is little bit confusing, i will rework this.